# difference between concatenating variables and constants in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out why C does this. It's a very simple string concatenation code but I get very different outputs depending on what goes into strcat.

Can someone shed some light on this?

```c
// With all declared variables
char * hello = "HELLO";

char * world = "WORLD";

char * space = " ";

char * say_hello(){
  char * out = "";
  strcat(out,hello);
  strcat(out,space);
  strcat(out,world);
  return out;
}

main(){
   puts(say_hello()); 
}

// outputs "HELLO WORLD"
```

```c
// With all hello as declared variable

char * hello = "HELLO";

char * say_hello(){
  char * out = "";
  strcat(out,hello);
  strcat(out," ");
  strcat(out,"WORLD");
  return out;
}

main(){
   puts(say_hello()); 
}

// outputs "HELLOELLOLOELLO"
```

```c
// With all hello and world as declared variable

char * hello = "HELLO";

char * world = "WORLD";

char * say_hello(){
  char * out = "";
  strcat(out,hello);
  strcat(out," ");
  strcat(out,world);
  return out;
}

main(){
   puts(say_hello()); 
}

// outputs "HELLOELLOWORLD"
```

```c
// With all constants

char * say_hello(){
  char * out = "";
  strcat(out,"HELLO");
  strcat(out," ");
  strcat(out,"WORLD");
  return out;
}

main(){
   puts(say_hello()); 
}

// outputs "HELLO WORLD"
```

Comment: You can't safely use `strcat` with a pointer like that; you'll need to specify the length of `out`...

Comment: You also can't return a pointer to a pointer on the stack such as your `char *out`.

Comment: You really should read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: In C, if you cannot explain in detail what your pointer is pointing to, how big that area is and what gives you the right to write there ... your code is wrong 99 out of a 100 times.

Comment: I get that it's dangerous code. I'm trying to figure out why something like these examples occurs, ie, Is it to do with how the pointers are laid out in memory etc... For instance, the "HELLOELLOLOELLO" returned via the second case is not random, but consistently the same - so it's not undefined behaviour in the strict sense.

Answer (score 8):

All of the code are invalid and dangerous.

First of all, modifying string literal is prohivited and trying to do so invokes *undefined behavior*. [`strcat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) will modify the string passed as the first argument, so you must not pass string literals (or pointers pointing at string literals) there.

Secondly, `""` is one-element array `{'\0'}`. It is not capable to store the string created by concatination. You have to allocate enough space.

Note that life of non-static local array ends on returning from the function, so you have to allocate eithor dynamically or statically.

Dynamic allocation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char * say_hello(){
  char * out = calloc(32, sizeof(*out)); /* allocate */
  if (out == NULL) exit(1); /* check if allocation succeeded */
  strcat(out,hello);
  strcat(out,space);
  strcat(out,world);
  return out;
}
```

Static allocation (warning: this is not thread-safe):

```
char * say_hello(){
  static char out[32];
  out[0] = '\0';
  strcat(out,hello);
  strcat(out,space);
  strcat(out,world);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the obligatory admonition about preferring `strncat` to `strcat` ;-)

Comment: One of the most frequent dupes

Comment: @0___________ I think MikeCAT's answer here went into more specific detail regarding OP's situation than the dupes...

Comment: please see my comment above. I get how to make it work. I want to know why it doesn't work. how does the second case even happen?